# Excel table / chart issue when updating the select data to a smaller amount

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I believe I have a simple fix but cannot find the answer anywhere online.

**I have a table that looks something like:**

```
date / total1 / total2 / total3
mon  / xxx    / xxxx   / xxxxx
tue  / xxx    / xxxx   / xxxxx
```

and so on.

I have created a chart off of this table which has worked fine. Each day I add another row with the current date and my new numbers.  The chart updates itself with the added information.

My problem started when i wanted to drop off the older dates from the bar chart.  I changed the range in select data to the days i wanted on the chart.  Since then any new days worth of data i enter to not automatically update on my chart.  I have to manually go in and change the range each day.  What did i break by changing the range that the chart is not updating anymore.

Comment: please saw your data and chart with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The chart updates as data is added to or removed from the table, as long as entire columns of the table are used. As soon as you adjust the data range to start in the middle of the table, you no longer are using the whole column, so Excel stops updating the chart.